# How to grow a single tree model with continuous and categorical predictors?

Tags: machine-learning, cart

I'm trying to implement the **recursive binary splitting algorithm** to grow a simple tree model. My aim is that it serves both for regression and classification trees.

**My problem is choosing which variable to split when I have both continuous and categorical predictor variables.**

$$f: X \rightarrow Y$$
$$ X : \{X_1 = Discrete, X_2 = Continuous\}$$

I understand that for continuous variables we use the residual sum of the squares (RSS) of the two regions (*given an optimal split point*) to determine which minimizes this metric. On the other hand, for categorical variables we use the information gain criterium to determine which variable maximizes this metric.

But **I don't understand how to relate categorical and continuous variables criterium in order to choose the following predictor to split and also how to compute the respective metrics when I have the following scenarios**:

- RSS when I have continuous predictors vs categorical response
- Information gain criterium when I have categorical predictors vs continuous response